# Selecting a newly added row in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to be able to select the newly added row (it's always added last), but it seems to be impossible after grid reload.

Is there a reliable way to select the last row after grid reload? This is the code I have now, and the grid reloads just fine but the last id is undefined. Trigger reload does not implement promises (then) so I can't tap into that. Any ideas?

```
 $('#mygridid').trigger('reloadGrid');    
 var lastRowId = $('#mygridid').find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:last").attr('id');
```

We are using the free version 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to append the code, which you posted, with the line

```
$('#mygridid').jqGrid("setSelection", lastRowId, false, null);
```

It should work if you reload local grid, for example. If you loads the data from the server, then your code should be more safe, for example, the following:

```
var mySelectionLastRow = function () {
    this.p.selrow = null;
    this.p.selarrrow = [];
    if (this.rows.length > 1) {
        var lastRowId = this.rows[this.rows.length - 1].id;
        $(this).jqGrid("setSelection", lastRowId, false, null);
    }
    $(this).unbind(".myLastRowSelection", mySelectionLastRow);
};
$("#mygridid").bind("jqGridGridComplete.myLastRowSelection", mySelectionLastRow);
// ...
$("#mygridid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The above code bind the `jqGridGridComplete` event to the function `mySelectionLastRow` before triggering `reloadGrid`. The function `mySelectionLastRow` will select the last row after reloading is finished and then unbind itself. Thus the next reloading of the grid will not select the last row. If you do need to force the selection every time on reloading the grid, then you can remove make the line with `unbind` call and make the above binding **before** creating the grid. As the result the `mySelectionLastRow` will be called every time even at the first loading the grid.